# In anisotropic media, is there a speed of light tensor like there is a refractive index tensor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, metric-tensor, speed-of-light, refraction

Lets say we have an homogeneous anisotropic medium where $\tilde\mu_r=\tilde\epsilon_r$ so we don't have to worry about polarization effecting anything. As such, the refractive index can be simply described by the 3x3 tensor $\tilde n$. Lets treat $\tilde n$ as a metric tensor to make some math easier.
$$\begin{matrix}\widetilde{g}=\widetilde{n}&\widetilde{\mathfrak{g}}=\frac{1}{\widetilde{g}}\\\end{matrix}$$
$$\frac{1}{n^2}={\vec{r}}^T\widetilde{\mathfrak{g}}\vec{r}$$
$$n\left(\vec{r}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{{\vec{r}}^T\widetilde{\mathfrak{g}}\vec{r}}}$$
Using that formula, we can find the refractive index in any given direction. If we plug in points on the surface of a unit sphere, we'll get an index ellipsoid. One might imagine we can do something similar to find a speed of light ellipsoid.
$$c\left(\vec{r}\right)=\frac{c_0}{\sqrt{{\vec{r}}^T\widetilde{g}\vec{r}}}$$
However, if this is true, we find that for anisotropic media, $c_0\neq\ \tilde{c}\tilde{n}$. As such, the relation $c=\frac{c_0}{n}$ breaks down. I'm not entirely sure which one is the one that actually breaks down though. For a 2D case:
$$\begin{matrix}\widetilde{g}=\left[\begin{matrix}E&F\\F&G\\\end{matrix}\right]&\widetilde{\mathfrak{g}}=\frac{1}{\widetilde{g}}=\frac{1}{EG-F^2}\left[\begin{matrix}G&-F\\-F&E\\\end{matrix}\right]\\\end{matrix}$$
$$\frac{1}{n^2\left(\theta\right)}=\frac{G\cos^2{\left(\theta\right)}-F\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}+E\sin^2{\left(\theta\right)}}{EG-F^2}={\vec{r}}^T\widetilde{\mathfrak{g}}\vec{r}$$
$$\color{orange}{n\left(\theta\right)=\sqrt{\frac{EG-F^2}{G\cos^2{\left(\theta\right)}-F\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}+E\sin^2{\left(\theta\right)}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{{\vec{r}}^T\widetilde{\mathfrak{g}}\vec{r}}}}$$
$$\color{blue}{c\left(\theta\right)=\frac{c_0}{\sqrt{E\cos^2{\left(\theta\right)}+F\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}+G\sin^2{\left(\theta\right)}}}=\frac{c_0}{\sqrt{{\vec{r}}^T\widetilde{g}\vec{r}}}}$$
$$\color{red}{\frac{c_0}{n\left(\theta\right)}}$$
[image: 2D Case]

As we can see, unlike the orange and blue lines, red isn't an ellipse. So which formula should I use for the speed of light?